# TikZ draw-Putting old calendar style date in left margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I'm working on the formatting of a text book.

The following picture shows the first thing I would like to do.

There are two things to achieve :

1. I would like to "draw" the date using `TikZ` so as to have later the possibility to make more evoluated formatting.
2. Then the "draw" must be put in the left margin.

[image]

The LaTeX code would be similar to the following one :

```
\section{Name of the class}

\subsection{Chapter A : Numeric activities}

\day{Mon.}{28}{Nov.}{2011}
\subsubsection{Lesson}
...

\subsubsection{For Tuesday Nov. 29}
...
```

Comment: Please don't ask "How do I achieve this layout", but rather a question about a specific feature that you're struggling with, one problem per question. This way other users who have a similar problem can benefit from your question and the solutions to it (No one's gonna ask for the same layout as you). It's no problem to ask several questions, if you've made some attempt yourself first. It's enormously helpful to see what you've tried so far to figure out what doesn't work. Is it putting something in the margin? Is it the table-layout with the colored cells? ...

Comment: You're right. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a `tikz` solution using [the `marginnote` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand*{\Date}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0pt,text width=1.5cm,align=center]
        \node [fill=orange] at (0,0)                                (dayofweek)  {#1};
        \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofweek)  +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#2};
        \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofmonth) +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (month)      {#3};
        \node [fill=orange] at ($(month)      +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\reversemarginpar% to put the margin pars on the left
\begin{document}
\marginnote{\Date{Mon.}{28}{Nov}{2011}}
\noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I center the text ?

Comment: Had already updated solution before you asked: use `align=center`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `tabular` environment to format the date, and then frame it using a `\fbox`; the `marginnote` command (from the homonymous package) lets you place the date as a marginal note. In the following example I illustrate this approach; the `\MyDate` command has one mandatory argument (the name of the day); the other three values are typeset automatically (of course, you can make all or some of this elements also customizable as arguments of the command):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,213,171}

\newcommand\MyDate[1]{%
  \marginnote{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \fbox{\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c}
    \rowcolor{mycolor} #1 \\
    \large\the\day \\
    \large\shortmonthname. \\
    \rowcolor{mycolor} \the\year
    \end{tabular}%
  }}%
}

\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

\MyDate{Mon.}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]