# Vertically aligning a marginnote and a section title

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, marginpar, marginnote

In the following code, the marginnote is logically aligned to the lipsum text. I would like to align the marginnote to the title of the section.

What's the trick to use ?

```
% Source : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36432/tiks-draw-in-left-margin-putting-old-calendar-style-date-in-margin

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{marginnote}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

    \newcommand*{\Date}[4]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0pt,text width=1cm,align=center]
            \node [fill=orange] at (0,0)                                (dayofweek)  {#1};
            \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofweek)  +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#2};
            \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofmonth) +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (month)      {#3};
            \node [fill=orange] at ($(month)      +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#4};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \reversemarginpar % To put the margin pars on the left


\begin{document}

\section*{One day} \marginnote{\Date{Mon.}{28}{Nov}{2011}}
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the `\marginnote` *inside*  the argument of `\section*` (and add `\normalfont\normalsize`).

```
\section*{One day\marginnote{\normalfont\normalsize\Date{Mon.}{28}{Nov}{2011}}}
```

EDIT: A better way is to change the definition of `\marginfont` to `\normalfont\normalsize`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar % To put the margin pars on the left
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand*{\Date}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0pt,text width=1cm,align=center]
    \node [fill=orange] at (0,0)                                (dayofweek)  {#1};
    \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofweek)  +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#2};
    \node [fill=white ] at ($(dayofmonth) +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (month)      {#3};
    \node [fill=orange] at ($(month)      +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#4};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{One day\marginnote{\Date{Mon.}{28}{Nov}{2011}}} 

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Last, but not least, you may change the vertical positioning of the `\marginnote` using its second optimal argument:

```
\section*{One day} \marginnote{\Date{Mon.}{28}{Nov}{2011}}[-30pt]
```