# Rule before one new section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, page-breaking, rules

I use rule so as to separate the differents sections. I would like to automate this so as to use the following syntax :

```
\section*{One day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\section*{Another day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\section*{One more day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\section*{One last day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]
```

**There are two problems to solve :**

1. The first section isn't preceded by a rule.
2. If one section is at the begining of one new page, it isn't preceded by a rule.

### Code to ameliorate

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \newcommand{\myRule}{%
        \vspace{0.5cm}\hrule%
    }

    \usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

% No rule ! 
\section*{One day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\myRule
\section*{Another day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\myRule
\section*{One more day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\newpage
% No rule !
\section*{One last day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) Will you be using unnumbered sections? (2) Will you be using a force `\newpage` to flush the page?

Comment: The newpage is for testing... I have to use unnumbered sections because I will also use the following formatting : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36554/positioning-marginnote-and-section/36556#36556 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By combining Mico's and Alan Munn's answer, here's a simpler code that should accomplish what's requested:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip 0.4pt\vspace{.8ex}%
   \normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {}
```

The space between the rule and the section title is .8ex (adjust to suit you).

Comment: Good ! I choose your solution because that's the smaller one.

Answer (score 6):

The following code is based on [this posting](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/d178fb88d533672f) to comp.text.tex in May 2011. No rule will be drawn if the section header is at the top of a page, including the very first page. This method works with both numbered and unnumbered section headers.

The amount of space between the end of a section and the subsequent rule and between the rule and the next section header, is controlled by the commands `\vspace{2\bigskipamount}` and `\vspace{\smallskipamount}`; change the arguments of the two `\vspace` commands to suit your preferences. The width of the rule by default is 0.4pt. (0.4pt seems to be something of a standard width for many lines in LaTeX...) You can change this setting too, of course.

Note that the command `\separatorrule` can be used on its own anywhere in the text, not just right before a section heading. Its two main distinguishing properties are (i) no rule will be drawn at the top of a page and (ii) no rule will be drawn later on in a page if the command is followed by an implicit or explicit `\clearpage` command, or similar-effect command such as `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\separatorrule}{% 
    \par\vspace{2\bigskipamount}
    \leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip 0.4pt 
    \vspace{\smallskipamount}\nointerlineskip}    
\let\origsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\separatorrule \origsection}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\section*{A} \lipsum[1]
\section{B}  \lipsum[2]
\section*{C} \lipsum[3]
\clearpage
\section*{D} \lipsum[4]
\section{E}  \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Finally, I have a strong hunch that the provider of the code for the separator rule in the comp.text.tex group, "Enrico Gregorio", is the very same person as `egreg` in the TeX Stack Exchange group. At any rate, the originality of my contribution to this posting is clearly minimal.

Comment: Actually the code was for another purpose, but it's possible that the OP wants the rule to disappear if a section falls at a page start.

Comment: @egreg: Good news, your code deals with the start-of-page concern as well. :-)

Comment: That's what I said, actually: leaders behave like glue, so they disappear at a page break. It depends on what the OP likes.

Comment: On the other hand, `\section` adds a break point, so the rule might get at the end of the page and the title on the subsequent page.

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer, since there are still some spacing issues that need to be resolved. At the very least, it could guide to a better solution.

Using a combination of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and some code from [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) it is possible to condition on page availability.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\newcounter{tmpcntr} \preto\newpage{\setcounter{tmpcntr}{0}}%

% Taken from the needspace package (http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\needspace}[3]{\par \penalty-100\begingroup
  \setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii
    #3
  \else
    #2
  \fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large\stepcounter{tmpcntr}}{\thesection}{\quad}{%
  \needspace{\dimexpr0.4pt+5mm+1.5\baselineskip\relax}%
    {\ifnumequal{\value{tmpcntr}}{1}{}{\titlerule\nobreak\kern5mm\nobreak}}% enough space
    {\break\vspace*{\topskip}}% not enough space
}

\begin{document}

% No rule ! 
\section*{One day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\section*{Another day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\section*{One more day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\newpage
% No rule !
\section*{One last day}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
​
```

The modified code from `needspace` provides

```
\needspace{<len>}{<less than len>}{<more than len>}
```

which executes `<less than len>` if there is less than `<len>` available on the page, otherwise it issues `<more than len>`.

Additionally, the `tmpcntr` counter is meant to be a reference of whether or not you start a new page, or the start of your document with a `\section`. If this counter is 1 (incremented within `\section`) no `\titlerule` is typeset.

Comment: @projetmbc: It's partial, but I'm sure you could tweak it to fit your needs.

Comment: I like the possibility to play with `titlesec`. Thanks for this !

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial answer using the `titlesec` package.  I've added a conditional to remove the rule for the first section.  If this applied to chapters, you'll need to add `\ruledfalse` to the definition of `\chapter`.  This doesn't solve the top of page problem, however, but I'll leave it up as an answer, since others who arrive here may not have that requirement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newif\ifruled
\titleformat{\section}
    {\ifruled\titlerule\else\global\ruledtrue\fi\vspace{.8ex}%
     \normalfont\bfseries} {}{0em}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{A section}
\section*{Another section}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: But I think the OP does not want the rule for the first section, or one at the top of a page

Comment: That's right, it's one critical and technical necessity... The same is true for sections at the beggining of one page.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood the problem, I thought that you wanted these.  I'll fix the answer (or delete it).