# Conflict between the packages titlesec and marginnote

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, titlesec, incompatibility, marginpar

In the following code, the use of the package `titlesec` modifies dramatically the formatting based on the package `marginnote`. The package `titlesec` is needed so as to use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36716/rule-before-one-new-section).

Is there one possibility to repair that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    %\usepackage{titlesec} % << Uncomment to see the changes... >>
    \usepackage{marginnote}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \reversemarginpar % To put the margin pars on the left
    \renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\sffamily\normalsize}

    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

    \definecolor{colorDateGene}{RGB}{230,120,120}
    \definecolor{colorDateToday}{RGB}{230,230,230}

    \newcommand*{\Date}[4]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            show background rectangle,
            inner frame sep=0pt,
            text width=1cm,
            align=center
        ]
            \node [fill=colorDateGene]  at (0,0)                                (dayofweek)  {\footnotesize{#1}};
            \node [fill=colorDateToday] at ($(dayofweek)  +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {#2};
            \node [fill=colorDateToday] at ($(dayofmonth) +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (month)      {#3};
            \node [fill=colorDateGene]  at ($(month)      +(0,-\baselineskip)$) (dayofmonth) {\footnotesize{#4}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Mon. 28 Nov.}
\section*{One day \marginnote{\Date{Mon}{28}{NOV}{2011}}}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Wed. 30 Nov.}
\section*{One day \marginnote{\Date{Wed}{30}{NOV}{2011}}}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Fri. 2nd Dec.}
\section*{One day \marginnote{\Date{Fri}{2nd}{DEC}{2011}}}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Mon. 5 Dec.}
\section*{One day \marginnote{\Date{Fri}{5}{DEC}{2011}}}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my [revised answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36556/510) to your former question: Instead of putting `\marginnote` inside `\section*`, change the vertical positioning of the `\marginnote` using its second optimal argument.

```
\section*{One day} \marginnote{\Date{Mon}{28}{NOV}{2011}}[-32pt]
```

Comment: To obtain the same formatting as the `\section` header, use `\marginnote{\bfseries...}`. Why `32pt`?

Comment: @Werner: The OP seems to want a marginnote in `\normalfont` that is nevertheless vertically aligned witth the sectioning title -- `32pt` is a crude aligning attempt, considering the marginnote's box.

Comment: Okay - `\normalfont` in the text has a `\baselineskip` of `14.5pt`, while that of the section heading is `22pt`, so I had thought `36.5pt`. But your visual attempt is definitely sufficient.