# How to align a marginpar with a section title

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

I wish to have brief information in a marginpar (or other solution) that aligns with the corresponding section (not section*) heading. So far the margin information is above or below the section title.

When run, the following MWE generates the margin text below the section title.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}\marginpar{\normalfont\normalsize Associated text}
Is it working?
\end{document}
```

I've searched the interwebs for help. I found [Vertical alignment of marginnote and section heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184771/vertical-alignment-of-marginnote-and-section-heading), but this article deals with section*. Alas, perhaps it can't be done...

But I hope that it can.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the `\marginpar` inside the argument for `\section`:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section[Section Heading]{Section Heading\protect\marginpar{\normalfont\normalsize Associated text}}
Is it working?
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, you can use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package instead and move the `\marginnote` command inside the argument for `\section`:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading\protect\marginnote{\normalfont\normalsize Associated text}}
Is it working?
\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument was used so the marginal note won't be in the ToC so `\protect` is not really needed; if the optional argument is not used, it is necessary to `\protect` the command.

Comment: With your example I was able to align my marginnote with my section title. I also discovered that the titlesec package was causing an issue with aligning the marginnote. Once I discovered that, I found the article [Conflict between the packages titlesec and marginnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36742/conflict-between-the-packages-titlesec-and-marginnote), which now makes sense.

Comment: For me it's still showing in the ToC too. Anyone experiencing the same?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*\marginfont{\normalcolor\normalfont\small}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section[Section Heading]{Section Heading\marginnote{Associated text}} 
%The optional argument of \section is used for the TOC
Is it working?
\end{document}
```

[image]