# Aligning `\marginpar` with section title

Tags: hyperref, marginpar, protected-macro

I tried to use a custom defined command, which uses `\marginpar`, inside `\section`. According to another [SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195335), I have to `\protect` it. But after some trial and error in my custom package, it breaks if I include `hyperref`. Is there some fix for this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{clecturesep}
\newcommand*{\lecturesep}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{clecturesep}%
    \marginpar{\small%
        Lect.~\theclecturesep{}\\
        {#1}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\lecturesep{11.07.23} % Works as expected

% Only works if we comment out hyperref
\section{Heeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaadeeeeeeeeeeeeer\protect\lecturesep{11.07.23}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't want the marginpar in the bookmarks, so use \texorpdfstring to exclude it.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I thought of that, but never imagined to use `\texorpdfstring` *and* `\protect` (directly before the `\lecturesep` command).

Comment: are you sure that you want the marginpar in the table of contents? If now it would make more sense to use the optional argument of section to exclude it alltogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making your `\lecturesep` part of the formatting of the section title, instead being part of the section title, to avoid [the issue that Ulrike pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690843/aligning-marginpar-with-section-title#comment1714377_690843)

One option is to use `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{clecturesep}
\newcommand*{\lecturesep}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{clecturesep}%
    \marginpar{\small%
        Lect.~\theclecturesep{}\\
        {#1}
    }%
}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\showlecturedate\gdef\showlecturedate{}}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand\showlecturedate{}
\newcommand\datedsection[1]{\def\showlecturedate{\lecturesep{#1}}\section}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\vspace{10pt}

\datedsection{11.07.23}[short title]{long title}

\datedsection{11.08.23}{long title titletitletitle titletitle  title}

\section[another]{longer title titletitletitletitle titletitle}

\datedsection{11.09.23}*{a title}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

If instead you want to avoid `titlesec`, with the `article` class you can define

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{clecturesep}
\newcommand*{\lecturesep}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{clecturesep}%
    \marginpar{\small%
        Lect.~\theclecturesep{}\\
        {#1}
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\datedsection[1]{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\lecturesep{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\vspace{10pt}

\datedsection{11.07.23}[short title]{long title}

\datedsection{11.08.23}{long title titletitletitle titletitle  title}

\section[another]{longer title titletitletitletitle titletitle}

\section{longer title}

\datedsection{11.09.23}*{another section}

\end{document}
```

which also builds fine with `hyperref` and yields

[image]